# Printing a table or list from a complex php array

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array that is generated from a third party. Which means I must work with the array format I have been given. Below is an array extract from var_dump.

```
{ 
    [0]=> object(stdClass)#3510 (3) { 
        ["privacy"]=> string(1) "0" 
        ["name"]=> string(11) "jumpsuits" 
        ["token"]=> string(12) "PD21B62AIFFM" 
    } 
    [1]=> object(stdClass)#3509 (3) { 
        ["privacy"]=> string(1) "1" 
        ["name"]=> string(8) "helmets" 
        ["token"]=> string(12) "PL68C79RKYAP" 
    } 
}
```

I am not a php programmer. But I do need to find a simple way in PHP to turn the array data in the format above into a three column table with the headings 'privacy', 'name' and 'token'.

If I could just get a starter for ten as to why `echo $array['name'][0]` returns nothing I think I could work the rest out.

Thank you

Comment: `$array[0]->name`.

Comment: `[index]` is used for arrays, `->property` is used for objects.

Comment: Really grateful for the explanation. That simple one liner gave me the perspective I needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is an array of objects, so you can loop it like this;

```
<?php
echo '<table>';
echo '<tr>';
echo '<td>';
echo 'Privacy';
echo '</td>';
echo '<td>';
echo 'Name';
echo '</td>';
echo '<td>';
echo 'Token';
echo '</td>';
echo '<tr>';
foreach($data as $row) {
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td>';
    echo $row->privacy;
    echo '</td>';
    echo '<td>';
    echo $row->name;
    echo '</td>';
    echo '<td>';
    echo $row->token;
    echo '</td>';
    echo '<tr>';    
}
echo '</table>';
```

Check it in codepad
http://codepad.org/MhcaKKRP

Comment: @user2755309 If an answer solved your problem, please, mark as solved

Answer (score 1):

```
    <?php    
        $array = json_decode(json_encode($object), true); // convert array of object to assoc array
        //all array:
        var_dump(array_column($array, 'privacy')); //privacy as array
        var_dump(array_column($array, 'name')); //name as array
        var_dump(array_column($array, 'token')); //token'
        //specific data:
        $data['privacy'] = array_column($array, 'privacy');
        $data['name'] = array_column($array, 'name');
        $data['token'] = array_column($array, 'token');
        
        echo $data['name'][0];
        //etc
```

Comment: Thank you all. The answers have helped me understand my shortcomings, And have  answers have solved my problem.

Comment: If ny answer help you, please mark as sloved